# How can I maximize UDP Packet Size?

Tags: windows, udp, packet, gameserver, maximum

I am a gamer. I play UDP-based games. I want to increase the packet size. I know the UDP packet size is 1024 but i want to increase this packet size even more. I want to increase the performance I get on the UDP-based games. I'm new to this so please help me in simple terms.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The content of an UDP packet is determined by the software that sends it. If the game does not allow to change the packet size you have to use it as it is.

Comment: I see, do you know anything to increase the performance of the UDP?